Tapir validation to reject unknown query parameters
If I have a tapir endpoint, has .in(query[Option[String]])("foo"), and the request has ?foobar=baz, is it possible to add validation logic to it, that will reject the request instead of silently ignoring the unknown parameter and handing me foo=None as input?

Do you mean in an automatic and generic way? Otherwise you can access undeclared query parameters with queryParams or extractFromUrl and implement it manually.

Yeah, I am looking for something generic ... But maybe I can still make it generic enough ... if you point me to what exactly this queryParams thing is :) What object do I call it on? Is it available somehow in serverLogic?

You can use in(queryParams) as you'll get the whole query param map as an input in your server logic yes. Reference: https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/ios.html

Oh, I see, you mean I can just capture the entire query, and then handle all of the parsing/validation myself? Nah ... that's too much work. Kinda defeats the whole point of using tapir in the first place ...

I meant to use both query and queryParams. Only using queryParams to check if there's parameters provided that you didn't except. But I'll keep the expected parameter defined with query so that parsing/validation is done by Tapir. I can try to write an answer with a code sample.

You could implement something like the following:
endpoint
  .get
  // Define input query string as usual
  .in(query[Option[String]]("foo"))
  // Add an extra input that reads all query params
  .in(
    queryParams
      // And validate that they contain only the ones you want
      .validate(
        Validator.Custom { params => 
          ValidationResult.validWhen(params.toMap.keySet.forall(p => p == "foo"))
        }
      )
  )

If you call the endpoint with a foobar query param you'd get a HTTP 400 response with body:

Invalid value for: query parameters (expected value to pass validation, but got: foobar=baz)

I guess you can probably iterate to make this a bit more generic for your usage.
